# doxygen: documenting a function pointer parameter of a function

Tags: c, function-pointers, doxygen, function-parameter

I have this:

```
/**
 * \details Initialization for _LWASPv1_
 * \param[in]   cbDeliver   Callback called to submit 'buff' (input parameter containing
 *                          bytes) to the physical layer for actual sending
 * \param[in]   cbReceived  Callback called when a correct LWASP frame is received. 'payload'
 *                          input parameter contains the decoded payload
 */
void LWASPv1_Init(int (*cbDeliver)(const uint8_t *buff, int len), int (*cbReceived)(const uint8_t *payload, int len));
```

I should document the function pointers (using doxygen) without typedef if possible. How can I do it?

Comment: With the \param the argument is documented. The data type of the argument is not documented but only shown, see e.g. when using int or float as data type. When you would like to document more about te data type I think you should document it either inline in the parameter description or otherwise separately with a typedef. Personally I think a typedef in the code is preferable as at that moment you can use it in the argument list and as definition for the underlying function (consistency in case of changes). Or did I miss something?